# React-Native-AsyncStorage save integer item

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I am try to save integer variable to the AsyncStorage, however it return me the error

> the bind value at index 1 is null

## SET Item

This is the code that i save item

```
AsyncStorage.setItem(
      Common.CURRENT_CHILD,
      this.state.child.toString(), //14
      () => {
        NavigationService.navigate('Home', {
          childName: this.state.childName
        });
      }
    );
```

## GET Item

This is the code that i retrieve item

```
    AsyncStorage.getItem(Common.CURRENT_CHILD, (err, result) => {
      if (result === null) {
       console.log(err);
     } else {
      this.setState(
     {
        child: result
     },
      () => {
        console.log('Result -', result);
      }
    );
  }
})
```

Comment: Are you trying to fetch it immediately you navigate to Home? Also did you log `this.state.child.toString()` value?

Comment: I just navigate to Home once save the item. The  `this.state.child.toString` will be the integer variable, e.g. 14

Comment: Try `await AsyncStorage.setItem` and see it that works.

Answer (score 1):

```
AsyncStorage.setItem(
  Common.CURRENT_CHILD,
 ""+ this.state.child.toString(), //14
  () => {
    NavigationService.navigate('Home', {
      childName: this.state.childName
    });
  }
);
```

you can write "" while set item to Asyncstorage and try to use console.log while getting Item before if statement or

write

```
  AsyncStorage.setItem(
      Common.CURRENT_CHILD,
     ""+ this.state.child, //14
      () => {
        NavigationService.navigate('Home', {
          childName: this.state.childName
        });
      }
    );
```